# Desabilitar botão em janela modal usando Jquery

Tags: jquery, modal

possuo uma janela modal com um botão, e gostaria que, ao pressionar o botão (uma tag a), o mesmo fosse desabilitado e apresentasse "Aguarde..."

Vejam o meu código:

```
//#idDivModal4 -> modal
//.btn-enviar-lembrete -> tag a (botão)

 $('#idDivModal4').on('click', '.btn-enviar-lembrete', function(){   
 event.preventDefault();     

     $(this).prop("disabled",true);
     $(this).prop("value","Aguarde.."); 

});
```

Modal:

```
...
 <a class="btn btn-danger btn-enviar-lembrete">Enviar lembrete</a>
```

Porém, o mesmo não está funcionando.
O que estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para criar um botão você não precisa necessariamente coloca-lo dentro de uma tag `<a href...`, você pode simplesmente criar com;

```
<button class="btn-enviar-lembrete">Enviar</button>
```

O javascript ficara assim;

```
$('.btn-enviar-lembrete').on('click', function() {
    $(this).prop({
        disabled: true,
        innerHTML: 'Aguarde...'
  });
});
```

Mas se preferir você também pode colocar uma tag de link ao redor;

```
<a href="">
    <button class="btn-enviar-lembrete">
       Enviar
    </button>
</a>
```

Lembre-se que as tags `a` tem por padrão um comportamento padrão que é de "recarregar a pagina", então para evitar que este link faça sua função `padrão`, adicione o parametro `event` dentro da `function` e depois diga ao `jquery` para "prevenir o comportamento padrão".

```
$('.btn-enviar-lembrete').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop({
        disabled: true,
        innerHTML: 'Aguarde...'
  });
});
```

## [Veja funcionando no JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rgkva514/)

Comment: Deu certo!!!! Obrigado a todos.

Comment: @Luis fiz uma alteração, veja se entende melhor.

Answer (score 0):

$(".#btn-enviar-lembrete")

Remova o ponto antes do # pois ou é uma classe ou é um id.

## btn-enviar-lembrete = id

.btn-enviar-lembrete = classe

Verifique antes pois o evento do jquery está com classe e a ação dentro do evento está com id e com o ponto antes do id.

Comment: Pessoal, eu tinha copiado e editado o código aqui, troquei o . pelo # em algumas linhas, mas já editei a pergunta.. Fiz o que me sugeriram mas ainda não funcionou :/

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

```
 $('#idDivModal4 #btn-enviar-lembrete').click(function() {
       $(this).prop("disabled",true);
       $(this).prop("value","Aguarde.."); 
 });
```

ou como esta o teu codigo

```
  $('#idDivModal4').on('click', '#btn-enviar-lembrete', function(){   
  event.preventDefault();     

 $("#btn-enviar-lembrete").attr("disabled", true);
 $("#btn-enviar-lembrete").attr('value', 'Aguarde...');
```

para alem disso tens una confusao entre o . e o # 
o "." -> equivale a classe o "#" ao id dos objectos

Comment: so agr me apercebi q era isso que ja fazias.. ao ver o click pensei q tivesses a invocar a funcao click. vou editar a resposta